# Test whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{n}}{n}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am trying to solve this using an integral test, but I am unsure whether or not this is correct.

Let $f:[2,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(t)=\frac{\ln{(t)}}{t} >0\  \forall t\geq2$.

Now $f'(t)=\frac{1-\ln{(t)}}{t^2} < 0 \ \forall t> e$.

$\implies f(t)$ is positive and decreasing $\forall t>e$.

Let $N_e \in \mathbb{N}$ be s.t. $N_e>e$.

We may now use the integral test to determine if $\sum_{n=N_e}^\infty \frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}$ converges or diverges.

$$\int\limits_{N_e}^\infty \frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}dn = \lim_{b\to\infty}\int\limits_{N_e}^b \frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}dn $$
Let $u=\ln{(n)} \implies du=\frac{1}{n}dn$

$$\implies \lim_{b\to\infty}\int\limits_{N_e}^b \frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}dn =\lim_{b\to \infty} \int\limits_{\ln{(N_e)}}^{\ln{(b)}}udu \\ = \lim_{b\to \infty}[\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{(b)}}_\text{Diverges}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\ln^2{(N_e)}}_\text{Converges}]$$
Thus $\sum_{n=N_e}^\infty \frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}$ diverges $\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks great.  You checked that $f(t)$ was monotone decreasing, then showed that the improper integral diverged.

However, you could've gotten to your result a lot faster with the comparison test.  For all $n > e$, we have:

$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{n}$$

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, then...

Comment: Thank you! :). The only reason I used the integral test, was because this came out of my set of notes asking "Can the integral test be used to test for convergence for the following series... and if yes, test it using the integral test"

Comment: Glad I could help!  It comes down to personal preference in a lot of cases.